# Insert space after each second bar

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I have a bar plot which shows 7 bars for one xtick. I want to group two bars by inserting some space after each second bar. I tried to use xshift in the \addplot command, but the color of the bar disappeared. Do you know how to do this in an easy way?

This is the main part of my axis-definition:

```
    ybar=1pt,
    bar width=5pt,
    scaled ticks=false,
    xtick={0,1,2,3},
    xticklabels from table={\nsdata}{[index]0},
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        rotate=45,
        xshift=-2mm,
        yshift=1mm
    },
    enlarge x limits=0.15,
```

The bars look like this currently:

[image: bars now]

I want something like this:

[image: what I want]

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.  In particular, show where you tried to add `xshift` to `\addplot`.

Comment: If you use `\addplot +[...]` then the settings in `...` will be appended to the existing settings, unlike `\addplot [...]` (note no `+`), where they will overwrite existing settings. I don't know if that will help in this case though.